# Im confused on how this function is being called, there is no call for it?

Tags: swift, for-loop

I'm confused on how `getFunctionNeededForReference` is running. There is no call for it and where are the functions returned to? where are they going? I know they are being referenced but where are the functions going to, there is not call for getFunctionNeededForReference in the beginning? there is no call sending the argument flag anyway?

```
func add ( a: Int , b : Int)-> Int {

    //returing a result and not a variable
    return a + b


}

func multiply ( a: Int, b: Int) -> Int{

    return a * b


}

// declaring a function as a variable, it takes in 2 Ints and returns an Int
var f1 : (Int, Int)-> Int

f1 = add

f1 = multiply

// Function as a parameter

func arrayOperation (f: (Int, Int) -> Int , arr1: [Int] , arr2: [Int]) -> [Int]

{

    // Declaring and initializing an empty array to return
    var returningArray = [Int]()

    for (i, val) in enumerate(arr1)
    {


        returningArray.append(f(arr1 [i], arr2 [i]))

    }


    return returningArray

}

arrayOperation(add, [2,3,4], [4,5,6])

arrayOperation(multiply, [2,3,4], [4,5,6])

//Function as a return value

func getFunctionNeededForReference (flag : Int)  -> (Int,Int) ->Int

{
    if flag == 0 {

        return add

    }else {
                return multiply

    }


}
```

Comment: Nice formatting of code makes more readable and understandable and is generally worth the  time, especially when you expect other to  review it. Randomly added blank lines do not help. Consistency also helps.

Comment: sorry, I'm new to this website, idk how you did that where the code is all organized in this highlighted grey area, I couldn't get all the code in the highlighted grey area, how do you do that?

Comment: Look at the tool bar and the help (mouse over to see descriptions.

Answer (score 0):

What you've posted is just some example code showing things that Swift supports. It's not code that's useful for anything. It's just demonstrating Swift's syntax for first-class functions.

If you don't understand what “first-class functions” means, you can look up the term in your favorite search engine and find many explanations.